# How to work around Windows error 8x90070057?

Tags: windows

So today I was trying to copy a simple .PDF file from a local folder on my machine to a network folder and every time I  tried to move the file I would get an error dialog box which would state that I was passing a wrong parameter and give me the error code of 8x90070057.

Does anyone know of a way to work around this error so that I can get this file copied?

- I have tried renaming the file with
  an underscore in front.
- I have tried copying from my local
  folder to my desktop and then to the
  remote folder.
- I have tried hunting down anything
  that might be using the file.

An example of the file name is: `Flowers & Trees.pdf`

Comment: You sure that is the correct error code?

Comment: Rename it to Flowers.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer to this problem by doing a simple thing. I renamed the document to `Flowers_and_Trees.pdf`. Seems like the main issue for this problem came from have an ampersand in the middle of the file name and Windows was having some trouble in figuring out what to do with it. Once I renamed the file without the ampersand, I was able to copy and paste with no problems.